# The best way to integrate SWF to html page

Tags: javascript, html, apache-flex, flash

What html-tags I should to use? May be some JS libs?

Of course, better if this will be cross-browser and platform independent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer the SWFObject JS available here:

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

Includes the lib and docs.

Answer (score 1):

The most popular and "standard" is [SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

If you use jQuery, [flashembed from jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/flashembed.html) is great too.